# How to convert or equalize Query<Map<String, dynamic>> to List

Tags: list, firebase, flutter

I have BrandList in my Firebase like this; [image: Brand Doc]

How can I convert or equalize this Firebase List to List.

I tried this;

```
var brandsRef = _firestore.collection("vehicles1").where("Brands");
    List brandsList = brandsRef;
```

But I got this error "A value of type 'Query<Map<String, dynamic>>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List'."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the document Id to get the query and then you can get the data which returns a Map.

From that Map, you can supply the key to retrieve the value. In this case, the key is "Brands".

```
var brandsQuery = await _firestore.collection("vehicles1").doc(document Id).get();
List brandList = brandsQuery.data()["Brands"];
```

Answer (score 0):

First I would suggest to create a model of your class Brand in addition to the jsonSerialization classics:

```
class Brands {
  Brands({this.brandName});
  List<String> brandName;

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'Brands': brandName,
    };
  }

  factory Brands.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return Brands(
      brandName: List<String>.from(map['Brands']),
    );
  }

  String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

  factory Brands.fromJson(String source) => Brands.fromMap(json.decode(source));
}
```

Then you need to add a few steps to the way you retreive elements:

```
   var response = _firestore.collection("vehicles1").where("Brands").get();

   final results =
        List<Map<String, dynamic>>.from(response.docs.map((e) => e.data()));
   Brands brands =
        results.map((e) => Brands.fromMap(e)).toList();
```